# ¿Cómo separar el contenido de un String a una lista en Java?

Tags: java

Quiero separar el contenido del siguiente String que contiene una ecuación:

`String cadena="(10+30)*5";`

a una lista, incluyendo los separadores que serian los signo y paréntesis. El resultado deseado sería:

```
cadena String[]={"(","10","+","30"+")","*","5";
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Por qué no te ha salido? ¿Qué errores te ha dado?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aquí tienes una posible solución, no es muy elegante pero se entiende bien.

```
String cadena = "(10+30)*5";

ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isDigit(cadena.charAt(i))) {
    sb.append(cadena.charAt(i));
    if (i == cadena.length() - 1) {
      resultado.add(sb.toString());
    }
  } else {
    if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
      resultado.add(sb.toString());
      resultado.add(Character.toString(cadena.charAt(i)));
      sb.setLength(0);
    } else {
      resultado.add(Character.toString(cadena.charAt(i)));
    }
  }
}
//La variable resultado contendrá [(, 10, +, 30, ), *, 5]
```

Si necesitas que sea un array puedes convertirlo desde el `Arraylist` facilmente:

```
String[] stringArray= resultado.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, el código se ve más pequeño que el que yo hice, lo probaré mil gracias .

Answer (score 0):

Una solución utilizando "SPLIT"

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena = "(10+30)*5";

    String[] output = cadena.split("(?=[-+*/()])|(?<=[^-+*/][-+*/])|(?<=[()])");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

Salida:

```
[(, 10, +, 30, ), *, 5]
```